# Coin Flipping Expected Values

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If a fair coin is flipped $n$ times, what are the expected values (in terms of $n$) of:
1. The length of the longest run?
2. The number of runs of length 1?
3. The total number of runs?

I tried working it out for some small values, but could not find a sufficiently exploitable/noticeable pattern to solve any of these.

For example, for 1 coin the answers are 1,1,1. For 2 coins, the answers are 1.5,1,1.5. For 3 coins, the answers are 2,10/8,2. So for questions 1 and 3, I suspect the answer is $\frac n 2 +0.5$, but I don’t know how to prove it. For question 2, I don’t know how to prove it AND I haven’t found a pattern.

Comment: It´s motivating people to give a reply if you show what you have tried.

Comment: For 2, what is the chance a given flip is a run of 1?  It is different for the first and last flips from all the rest.  Use the linearity of expectation.  For 3, what is the chance a given flip is the first in a run?  Again, linearity of expectation.  I believe 1 has been answered here.

Comment: Please search online the keywords "Mark Schilling Bernoulli run" as a start.